# Upgrading Magento From Version 1.6.2 to 1.7

Tags: mysql, upgrade

Im currently running 1.6.2 now for about a year, this is from day one introductory into magento, so over the year I have gained more knowledge with magento, and I would like to move over to new versions and also update when available.

From what I understand, dont touch core, but I can update everything, what im concerned about is the database though.

So for instance I have a base 1.6.2 install with the live database (copied). And I would like to just add the 1.7 files into the directory and overwrite where nessecary. I guess what im asking is, does the database change on versions?

Answer (score 5):

> I guess what im asking is, does the database change on versions?

Yes it does. What changes between the versions can be seen in the update and data scripts in the `sql` and `data` directory in the different `Mage_*` modules, e.g.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/...
```

Comment: Sorry Adam, I missed that part of the question: Fabion is correct, your new version will be reflected in core_resource

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1) Make a complete working backup of your site
2) Copy the 1.7 files into you project (Using RSYNC or FTP)
3) Run your upgrade - Test

On your production site remember to enable the Maintenance flag before you start, before you start

Once you have confirmed that the above works then you can do it on live. Of course make sure you make a backup of your live before you do the above on production.

Answer (score 0):

When you looked at the diff files between 1.6.* to 1.7 ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.7.0.0-alpha1/1.6.2.0-1.7.0.0-alpha1.diff.bz2), you can see the Modules/mysql4-upgrade-* files. Most of these files have included the changes to the database. 
If you want to copy only necessary files, I would suggest to copy the file you needed to your environment instead of dumping the whole core directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just copying file over is not enough. Some old files are dropped from version to version and sometimes leaving old files in place causes issues.

I recommend doing "regular" update using `./mage` script.